# shell script - run list of commands

Tags: shell, automation

```
for i in `cat foo.txt`
do
    $i
done
```

And I have a input file "foo.txt", with list of commands.

```
ls -ltr | tail
ps -ef | tail
mysql -e STATUS | grep "^Uptime"
```

when I run the shell script, it executes, but splits the commands in each line at spaces i.e for first line it executes only "ls", then "-ltr" for which I get command not found error.

How can I run each list as one command?

## why am I doing this?

I execute lot of arbitrary shell commands including DB commands. I need to have a error handling as I execute each command(each line from foo.txt), I can't think of what can go wrong, so the idea is put all commands in order and call them in loop and check for error (#?) at each line and stop on error.

Comment: See @lasrks answer. Additionally, `for i in \`cat foo.txt\`` is a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use Of `cat`*) If you ever find yourself doing `cat something` and you are not *concatenating* `something` with another file -- it's likely a *UUOc*. Instead redirect your file to the loop, e.g. `while read -r line; do ##stuff with line; done < foo.txt` Do not `eval $line` to try and execute each line. `eval` is only once character away from *evil*. Source the file as the answer shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
set -e
. ./foo.txt
```

`set -e` causes the shell script to abort if a command exits with a non-zero exit code, and `. ./foo.txt` executes commands from `foo.txt` in the current shell.

---

> but I guess I can't send notification (email).

Sure you can. Just run the script in a subshell, and then respond to the result code:

```
#!/bin/sh

(
set -e
. ./foo.txt
)

if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "The world is on fire!" | mail -s 'Doom is upon us' you@youremail.com
fi
```

Comment: This does stop on error - but I guess I can't send notification (email).

Comment: @arsks - I tried your modified script, it does not stop on error, its does show "command not found error" I guess that is is raised by the subshell. I even tried adding "exit 1" after your echo statement in IF block. It does not stop it continues to next command in list.

Comment: This code works just fine (I even tested it!). If you're getting a "command not found" error you're making a basic mistake (e.g., not providing the correct path to a command).

Comment: sorry - yes it does works, I did not notice that the error check does not have "exit" due to which it was continuing (after error), I just added "exit", so it stops on error.

Answer (score 0):

Code mentioned.

```
for i in `cat foo.txt`
do
    $i
done
```

Please use   https://www.shellcheck.net/

```
This will result    _ 
    $ shellcheck myscript

Line 1:
for i in `cat foo.txt`
^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.
         ^-- SC2013: To read lines rather than words, pipe/redirect to a 'while read'   loop.
         ^-- SC2006: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked `...`.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2006)
for i in $(cat foo.txt)

$
```

Will try  while loop, and for test purpose content of foo.txt mentioned below

```
cat foo.txt
    ls -l /tmp/test
    ABC
    pwd



 while read -r line; do $line; if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then echo "Send email Notification stating  $line Command reported error "; fi; done < foo.txt

 total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec 24 11:41 test.txt
bash: ABC: command not found...
Send email Notification stating  ABC Command reported error
/tmp
```

In case error reported you can break the loop.
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_05.html

```
while read -r line; do $line; if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then echo "Send email Notification  stating  $line Command reported error "; break; fi; done < foo.txt

total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec 24 11:41 test.txt
bash: ABC: command not found...
Send email Notification stating  ABC Command reported error




 while read -r line; do eval $line; if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then echo "Send email Notification stating  $line Command reported error "; break; fi; done < foo.txt
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec 24 11:41 test.txt
   bash: ABC: command not found...
Send email Notification stating  ABC Command reported error
```

Comment: I tried your solution as well, I still see 2 issues. The commands are split at space eg: 
ls -ltr | tail will give error "ls: |: No such file or directory " 
and "ls: tail: No such file or directory"

Its traps/shows error, but it continues to following line/command

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/eval.1p.html  In above code use eval  while read -r line; do eval $line; if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then echo "Send email Notification stating  $line Command reported error "; break; fi; done < foo.txt